# My block do not find the template

Tags: magento

sorry for bad English. But if they can help me I appreciate it.
For something reason miha extension does not display the page when I send it to the server, my localhost is running, but the server does not, does anyone know what can it be? This is my xml file layout configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <reportneworders_adminhtml_reportneworders_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="reportneworders/adminhtml_reportneworders" name="product.report.grid.container" template="report/grid/container.phtml">

            </block>
    </reference>
</reportneworders_adminhtml_reportneworders_index>
```

Comment: Please change anything else instead of name="product.report.grid.container"

Comment: Hi, I have changed, but stil don't work.